# What is the better way to insert / replace 10-20 millions of records into a table in mysql(tokudb)

Tags: tokudb

Data Structure :

Main table (500 Millions) :

> CREATE TABLE `USER_DETAILS` (
>
> `visitor_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
>
> partition_id INT,
>
> related_text longtext,
>
> `creation_date` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>
> PRIMARY KEY (`visitor_id`,partition_id) )
>
> ENGINE=TokuDB
>
> PARTITION BY LIST (partition_id) (
>
> PARTITION p0 VALUES IN (0) ENGINE = TokuDB,
>
> PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (1) ENGINE = TokuDB,
>
> PARTITION p2 VALUES IN (2) ENGINE = TokuDB,
>
> PARTITION p3 VALUES IN (3) ENGINE = TokuDB,
>
> PARTITION p4 VALUES IN (4) ENGINE = TokuDB,
>
> PARTITION p5 VALUES IN (5) ENGINE = TokuDB,
>
> PARTITION p6 VALUES IN (6) ENGINE = TokuDB,
>
> PARTITION p7 VALUES IN (7) ENGINE = TokuDB,
>
> PARTITION p8 VALUES IN (8) ENGINE = TokuDB,
>
> PARTITION p9 VALUES IN (9) ENGINE = TokuDB);

Intermediate table (10-20 Millions):

> CREATE TABLE `USER_DETAILS_INTERMEDIATE` (
>
> `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>
> visitor_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
>
> `partition_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>
> `related_text` longtext,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

Problem :

> Taking too much time when i transfers data from intermediate table to main table.

I tried following solutions :

solution 1 :

> REPLACE INTO USER_DETAILS(visitor_id, partition_id, json_list)
>
> SELECT visitor_id     ,partition_id   ,related_text
>
> FROM USER_DETAILS_INTERMEDIATE a

solution 2 (running following statement in loop : 10000 rows per loop):

> REPLACE INTO USER_DETAILS(visitor_id, partition_id, json_list)
>
> SELECT visitor_id     ,partition_id   ,related_text
>
> FROM USER_DETAILS_INTERMEDIATE a
>
> WHERE id BETWEEN var_min_id AND var_max_id ;

Above query is taking both time.

Is there another way to improve this..?